# Повторное выполение запроса если предыдущий результат ничего не вернул

Tags: plsql

Можно ли изменит запрос так, что бы если результат его выполнения ничего не возвращает он выполнялся без учета одного из параметров.
Для примера я написал запрос:

```
select * from students s
where s.group_id = decode( :group_id , null, d.group_id , :group_id)
and s.students_id= :students_id
```

Мне нужно его изменить так чтобы, если students_id не удалось найти в группе group_id запрос вернул запись с любым group_id.
Или мне придется писать функцию которая будет два раза выполнять запрос?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, так:

```sql
select * 
from students s
where s.students_id= :students_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.group_id = decode( :group_id , null, d.group_id , :group_id)
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 2 
              END
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Сортировка (вернее, выражение сортировки) разделит набор без условия на 2 группы - записи, соответствующие условию, и остальные.

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW` отберёт только самую первую запись. А `WITH TIES` обеспечит отбор всех остальных записей, у которых критерий сортировки совпадает с таковым у первой записи. Т.е. если есть хоть одна запись, соответствующая условию - вернутся все записи, ему соответствующие, иначе вернутся все не соответствующие.

---

Если же нужна всегда только одна запись - при наличии с требуемой группой, иначе с любой, то просто убрать `WITH TIES`. Если же при отсутствии всё же есть какие-то приоритеты - добавьте второй уровень сортировки.